# Limit of a function with multiple radicals at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^{1/2}+3x^{1/3}+5x^{1/5}}{(3x-2)^{1/2}+(2x-3)^{1/3}} $$

I tried to divide the expresion with the highest power of $x$, but the problem is with the denominator.

Comment: What is the problem with the denominator? (If you divide the denominator by $x^{1/2}$ and bring the factor inside each of the parentheses, you should get something reasonable.)

Comment: @barakmanos Not quite...

Comment: Yes,exactly the answer is that.

Comment: No it's not (close, but not good enough). @lemon was right.

Comment: @barak manos Can u give the process?

Comment: @user146181: Both answers below are correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^{1/2}+3x^{1/3}+5x^{1/5}}{(3x-2)^{1/2}+(2x-3)^{1/3}} =\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2+3x^{1/3-1/2}+5x^{1/5-1/2}}{(3-2/x)^{1/2}+x^{1/3-1/2}(2-3/x)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the lower order terms since their effect is negligible at infinity:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^{1/2}+3x^{1/3}+5x^{1/5}}{(3x-2)^{1/2}+(2x-3)^{1/3}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^{1/2}}{(3x)^{1/2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
$$